# Build error with map_view, flutter & gradle?

Tags: gradle, dart, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

I get a build error using flutter version 1.2.2 and map_view version 0.0.14.

I tried to use this code in build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.2-4'
```

I followed all the steps here https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/map_view#-readme-tab-

I have an api-key but get the following build error

> Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the
>   android/ folder.
>   * Error running Gradle: ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\Almoit PC\Desktop\MyApp\Map\flutter_app2\android\gradlew.bat" exited
>   abnormally:
>
> Configure project :map_view
>   WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1.
>   Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
>   To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.2.51 and higher. Project 'android' is using
>     version 1.1.2-4.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 10s   Command: C:\Users\Almoit
>   PC\Desktop\MyApp\Map\flutter_app2\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

```
flutter doctor -v

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.437], locale en-AI)
    • Flutter version 1.2.1 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 8661d8aecd (10 weeks ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
    • Engine revision 3757390fa4
    • Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 33.4.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SPH L520 • 2d81b4cf • android-arm • Android 4.4.2 (API 19)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: So did you try using `Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.2.51 and higher` as the error states?

Comment: yes, I did. I have a problem with google packages